# Simple conditional failing

Tags: ios, objective-c, conditional-statements

I have a simple conditional which is failing:

```
 NSNumber *beaconMajor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:33995];
NSNumber *beaconMinor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:59204];
NSNumber *incommingMajor = beacon.major;
NSNumber *incommingMinor = beacon.minor;

NSLog(@"%d", [beaconMajor integerValue]);
NSLog(@"%d", [incommingMajor integerValue]);

NSLog(@"Pre big conditional");

//if the beacon is the one for the test content AND we are very near to it, show that content
if (incommingMinor == beaconMinor) {
    NSLog(@"Into big conditional");
    if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainToContent" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I'm grabbing two NSNumbers coming from an iBeacon, and am comparing them to two manually set numbers which I know to correspond.  Check the numbers when I log them, they are the same.  However the conditional doesn't accept them as being equal so doesn't trigger.

I can't see anything wrong, it's very simple as you can see.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing objects (addresses in memory), you need to compare the value of them:

```
if ([incommingMinor intValue] == [beaconMinor intValue])
```

Comment: Oh jees, time for a coffee I reckon!  Thanks.

Comment: :) It's ok, happened to me too

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing pointers addresses which will not be equal as `beaconMinor` and `incommingMinor` points to a different memory address.

compare the object number value as stated in Antonio's answer (compare the `intValue` of the instances)

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing `NSNumber` use `isEqual:`

If you are comparing integers then use `==`

---

```
if ([incommingMinor isEqual: beaconMinor]) {
```

or

```
if ([incommingMinor intValue] == [beaconMinor intValue]) {
```